# Camera code crashing on L.G G6 in Play store pre launch reports

Tags: android, android-camera, crash-reports, autofocus

i have an a simple app that takes a picture for sending it over to a server. The app works fine and all, but for some strange and unknown reasons it always crashes on LG-G6 devices in testing by google.

The pre launch report crash logs always points to following code which is setting **FOCUS** mode.
I have tried all flash modes yet the app crashes.

```
if(getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_AUTOFOCUS)) {
                        parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                        camera.setParameters(parameters); //line 328
}
```

Following is the excerpt from crash log

> FATAL EXCEPTION: ControllerMessenger Process:
>   com.localgsa.HcadPublicA, PID: 11403 java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   setParameters failed  at
>   android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)   at
>   android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:2034)   at
>   com.localgsa.hcad.activities.license_capture.LicenseFrontCaptureActivity.surfaceChanged(LicenseFrontCaptureActivity.java:328)
>     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:646)  at
>   android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:162)    at
>   android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2288)
>     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1306)    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6579)
>     at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
>     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)   at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)    at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
>     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)   at
>   androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.a(Interrogator.java:19)  at
>   androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:164)
>     at
>   androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:156)
>     at
>   androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:34)
>     at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.a(MotionEvents.java:75)
>     at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.a(MotionEvents.java:50)
>     at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.c(Tap.java:9)  at
>   androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.a(Tap.java:19)  at
>   androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.b(Tap.java:2)     at
>   androidx.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:22)
>     at
>   androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:9)
>     at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:78)
>     at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:94)
>     at
>   androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:3)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6316)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)

Can anyone provide me with some insight? This issue has been pestering me for a while.

P.S i don't have a physical LG G6 device with me. I have tested the app on  a slightly older LG device and the app ran fine.

Comment: Can you please post the code used to take the picture ?

Comment: Give us the rest of the logcat. You're missing a "Caused by"

Comment: @user8886048 Hi, app contains simple picture taking code... the above code is enclosed in the public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}

Also, the app runs fine on almost all other devices i have.

Comment: @TheWanderer posted